# Bootstrap styling breaks when I add own stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

This is what I have on my application.html.erb file.

```
<head>
   <title>Software & Cia.</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolineks-track': 'reload' %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

If I delete the application `stylesheet_link_tag`, bootstrap works just fine, but I want to add my own styling to some parts. Sorry for the noobish question, but tried to find a solution and can't get it working.

My application.scss is

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "boostrap";
```

My application.js is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree . here
```

Comment: Maybe is because your styles are overwriting the bootstrap? Do you have a lot of styles? Or any external libraries that could reset your HTML styles?

Comment: Just 2 files and it's breaking classes that I haven't edited.

Comment: try to import `bootstrap` directly in application.scss with the [gem bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) to avoid to include it inside your `<head>`

Comment: I already do this. Thought I needed to also do it inside <head>. Tried deleting it from <head> and the style breaks.

Comment: how is your application.scss file ? how do you import bootstrap and your custom scss files ?

Comment: Edited the question to add what you suggested @sovalina. Just import them in the <head> file as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @Italo but how do you import your custom files ?

Comment: My custom .scss are in assets/stylesheets. Don't they get imported in    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> @sovalina ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Bootstrap in rails, it's a good way to use the [bootstrap gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) (same for jquery)

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

This way you keep your application `<head>` clean:

```
<head>
  <title>Software & Cia.</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

Now your assets/stylesheets folder can be organize like that:

```
stylesheets
  |_ custom_folder
  |   |_ custom1.scss
  |   |_ custom2.scss
  |
  |_ application.scss
  |_ another_custom.scss
```

And you import all these files, bootstrap included, in your application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom_folder/custom1";
@import "custom_folder/custom2";
@import "another_custom";
```

- If you have multiple files inside a custom folder, you can even
  create an index.scss where you import all your files and just import
  `"custom_folder/index"` in application.scss
- If you override some boostrap variables in a file, import this one **before** bootstrap

Comment: Did evertything in here step by step, I was using the sass gem but it worked fine with this. Thank you!